# Дублирование CSS кода для одинаковых блоков на разных страницах?

Tags: html, css

Есть верстка, статические html, один css на все страницы. Есть повторяющиеся блоки, с почти одинаковыми стилями. Как лучше поступить, просто скопировать блок, сохранить классы, стили и тд. Или все же создать отдельный класс и скопировать стили? Логично, что скопировать проще, но если понадобится менять один из блоков, изменения будут и на другом. Привык к модульной структуре компонентов, но эта верстка не моя, что есть, то уже есть. Я бы предпочел продублировал код, интересно другое мнение. Спасибо!

Comment: Или разнесите код по классам, или для другого блока добавите классы со стилями, которые будут перекрывать/добавлять необходимое

Comment: Я бы посмотрел на потенциальную возможность расхождения стилей в будущем (проект активно развивается, будут доработки одного из модулей и т.д.), если вероятность довольно высокая - то скопировать. Если низкая, то уже можно подумать о том, чтобы сделать обобщение кода.